# How to scale shapes according to window size?

Tags: c#, wpf, scale

i have two shapes in a canvas. The requirement is, when user changes the window size, the size of these two shapes too have to be changed.

Think that there is a square and a triangle which is on top of the square. I created a simple house with these two shapes. The problem is, when I the size of these shapes according to the windows size, a gap forms between these two shapes and it doesn't look like a house anymore :)

any solution?

Comment: How you change size of these shapes according to the windows size?

Answer (score 1):

you might use Stretch-"Fill" to use all available space in your path, or use a ViewBox.